# What variety is this curvy courgette / zucchini with a bulge at the flower end?

Tags: identification, zucchini

This is a picture of courgette/zucchini from a plant I bought but no longer have the tag for. The shape shown is the same as every other courgette from the plant. They look like a coat hook to me!

The plant itself has relatively small leaves compared with the standard courgettes people grow, and the fruit is smaller too and probably a bit less prolific.

However, unlike the standard ones, the courgettes were also a little more crisp to eat, and didn't grow too large within a few days if left unpicked (the one shown was probably 2 weeks old and is larger than I generally picked them, as I didn't notice it for a while, but it was still delicious!). The plant has also lasted much much longer with no sign of mildew, and is still producing as we get into wintery weather.

I'm wondering if anyone can identify the variety? (it was purchased in New Zealand, but may still be grown elsewhere?)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be called ***zucchini tromboncino***. Here are [some pictures](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=zucchini%20tromboncino&qs=AS&sk=&FORM=QBIR&pq=zucchini%20trombon&sc=1-16&sp=1&qs=AS&sk=) that all look like yours. North American zucchini = European courgette. (BTW some of the pictures fall somewhere between funny and not quite NSFW.)

Comment: It may also go by the name "Zucchini Rampicante" it seems

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some variety of Cucuzza